# How to modify Spring Security filter chain at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring security and my config looks like this. I am using [Spring Security SAML](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml) library.

```
http
    .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(samlEntryPoint, extendedMetadata), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
    .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(samlEntryPoint, contextProvider), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider);

private FilterChainProxy samlFilter(SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint, SAMLContextProvider contextProvider) {
        List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<>();
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"),
            samlEntryPoint));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
            new MetadataDisplayFilter()));
        try {
            chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
                samlWebSSOProcessingFilter(samlAuthenticationProvider, contextProvider, samlProcessor)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SAMLDiscovery samlDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
        samlDiscovery.setMetadata(cachingMetadataManager);
        samlDiscovery.setContextProvider(contextProvider);
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"),
            samlDiscovery));
        return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
    }
```

Now since my app supports dynamic configuration, if the IDP SSO url is changed from `/saml/SSO` to something else, then following filter will not work as the url is hardcoded and the configuration will take effect only after server restart.

```
chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
                    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter(samlAuthenticationProvider, contextProvider, samlProcessor)));
```

Is there a way to change the filter at runtime? I can see the `getRequestMatcher()` method in [Official Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/api/org/springframework/security/web/DefaultSecurityFilterChain.html) but no way to set it. Am I approaching the problem in a wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can implement a customized RequestMatcher to check the url:

```
public class CustomizedAntRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String url = "/saml/SSO/**"; //change this line to get your dynamic configuration
        AntPathRequestMatcher antPathRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(url);
        return antPathRequestMatcher.matches(request);
    }
}
```

And then use the customized request matcher to replace the AntPathRequestMatcher:

```
chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new CustomizedRequestMatcher(),
                    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter(samlAuthenticationProvider, contextProvider, samlProcessor)));
```

Contact me if this way can not resolve your problem.

Comment: Adam, your answer helped. Could you also suggest how to modify during runtime the filters that I am adding in `line 1`

Comment: Hello, have you resolved this issue? I'm sorry I should be too late to reply this comment. About this issue, I'm not very clearly about your dynamic configuration. I think you can implement a bean to manage your configuration and get this bean in "line 1" and then get your configuration from that bean.